How to destroy a queue on ActiveMQ Artemis using management message
I am successfully using the ActiveMQ Artemis Management API to run admin commands on the broker. Creating messages, deleting them, moving them, restoring DLQ messages, pruning a queue, etc. all works fine. Except destroying a queue.
I use the following code:
Message request = queueSession.createMessage();
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(request, ResourceNames.BROKER, "destroyQueue​", queueName);
Message reply = managementRequestor.request(request);
        
if (JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(reply)) {
    System.out.println("Invoked management operation destroyQueue on server.");
} else {
    throw new JMSException("The management operation destroyQueue did not succeed.");
}

This results in the exception being thrown no matter which queue I try to destroy. Using the admin console I have no problem destroying the same queue so the broker has no real problem with destroying the queues I try to destroy.
The structure of my code is correct because I use it with many other management commands. There's something going on with the destroyQueue command.
I get no real error feedback either on the return message or in the log of the broker, so I have no idea what is going wrong.
What am I doing wrong here?

There may a timing issue where consumers are present on the queue when you attempt to destroy it.
In any case, if you want to get a better understanding about the nature of the failure you should use JMSManagementHelper#getResult(javax.jms.Message). The JavaDoc states:

Returns the result of an operation invocation or an attribute value.
If an error occurred on the server, hasOperationSucceeded(Message) will return false. and the result will be a String corresponding to the server exception.

For example:
Message request = queueSession.createMessage();
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(request, ResourceNames.BROKER, "destroyQueue​", queueName);
Message reply = managementRequestor.request(request);
        
if (JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(reply)) {
    System.out.println("Invoked management operation destroyQueue on server.");
} else {
    throw new JMSException("The management operation destroyQueue did not succeed. Result: " + JMSManagementHelper.getResult(reply));
}


This helped me find the actual problem, which I detailed in my own answer on this question.

Well...... Turns out there was a special invisible unicode character in the method name string in my code. :S After some detective work I was able to reconstruct how this happened; I copied the name of the method plus the opening '(' character from the documentation into my code. I corrected my code by removing the '(' character but there was an invisible zero width space character that Eclipse did not show/indicate. Anyone can reproduce this by copying the method signature from the documentation and putting it in an analyzer.
Even while debugging this special character was not shown by Eclipse which really screwed with me. The debugger showed a println statement with the correct value but after executing the line the console output suddenly had a visible extra space. Took me hours to figure this out, so I hope it helps someone else.

You aren't the first person to encounter this problem. Several folks have logged bug reports with the JDK for this (e.g. here). Once we switch to Java 17 this won't be a problem anymore.
